# PHPmailer reports: Could not execute: /usr/sbin/sendmail

Tags: phpmailer

Why?
I can send via mail() in PHP but I can't send via PHPMailer using IsSendmail()

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you sure the path `/usr/sbin/sendmail` is correct?

If yes, check also the permissions for sendmail are set correctly.

Comment: the path is correct, I verified it via phpinfo(); I don't know how to check or set permissions for sendmail, it's a shared hosting server.

Comment: Not every shared host supports sendmail. Create a support ticket & ask your host about it.

Answer (score 21):

I've had the same error. Solved it by commenting/deleting this:

```
$mail->IsSendmail();
```

Now it works correctly. I can send mails, and I receive them in my inbox.

Comment: Now this method has become `isSendMail()`, and yes it worked for me too.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue. Spent almost an hour checking logs, checking sendmail paths and testing php mail() and sendmail from command line to no avail. And finally all I did was restarted Apache using `apachectl -k graceful` and the universe was healed.

Comment: in mycase it was just "service php-fpm restart" && "service httpd restart"

Answer (score 1):

For me it's working with `$mail->IsSMTP()`.
`IsSendmail()` is looking for sendmail.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the bloc above. The default mail() function is enabled on all servers (i believe). In my case I was able to send basic html using the simple mail() function but when I used PHPMailer to do that I had that error.

So **I removed the part where it checks i.e. IsSendMail()** and all was fine. Now more exception thrown.

For people who want to use SMTP. First create an email account on your sever and then define its parameter in your code.

*Cheers,*

**Talha**

Comment: This is a misleading method name, but it's not a "check" for whether the mailer is sendmail, it's a declarative statement saying, "this mailer is sendmail."  https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/5251d331249900a8551442391265a3ec20200c8f/src/PHPMailer.php#L982

Answer (score 0):

Removing IsSendmail() just created another error for me, in the end the host provider had to remove safemode on the PHP settings.  It then worked

Edit By David Burdess

SafeMode should not be set on a live server! For example sites that run on Joomla or other CMS solutions it should not be enabled except in a testing environment

Answer (score 0):

PHP with enabled `safe_mode` on shared servers (and probably on others too) will fail to open `/usr/sbin/sendmail` (PHPMailer uses `popen`)