# Unable to send attach file in email in php

Tags: php

- to send attach file in email,

I downloaded the script from http://www.smarttutorials.net/php-script-to-send-email-with-attachment/

Error I was getting - Could not execute: /usr/sbin/sendmail

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHPmailer reports: Could not execute: /usr/sbin/sendmail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4393724/phpmailer-reports-could-not-execute-usr-sbin-sendmail)

Answer (score 0):

This means you don't have sendmail installed on the server. On a debian based Linux distribution use

```
sudo apt-get install sendmail
```

with CentOS or Redhat use

```
sudo yum install sendmail
```

If that still doesn't work then check the permissions of /usr/sbin/sendmail.