# Could not execute: /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, sendmail

I try to send an email via phpmailer and this is my code:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;       
$mail->isSendmail();

$mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'First Last');        
$mail->addAddress('whoto@example.com', 'John Doe');
$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer sendmail test';
$mail->AltBody= 'This is a plain-text message body';

if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
}
```

And I get this error:

> Could not execute: /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i

Any ideea why I get this error and why the email is not sending ?

I also contacted the company and they told me that sendmail is active and they even did a apache restart for me but I still get the same error. They told me that I should set a host mail.mydomain.ro in order to work, but in the phpmailer example I don't have any host to set.

UPDATE:
In case I try to use SMTP I get this error:

```
2017-01-25 19:56:44 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220-prime.mycompany.ro ESMTP Exim 4.87 #1 Wed, 25 Jan 2017 21:56:44 +0200 
220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited,220 and/or bulk e-mail.
2017-01-25 19:56:44 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO www.mywebsite.ro
2017-01-25 19:56:44 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-prime.mycompany.ro Hello www.mywebsite.ro [some ip]
                                  250-SIZE 52428800
                                  250-8BITMIME
                                  250-PIPELINING
                                  250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
                                  250-STARTTLS
                                  250 HELP
2017-01-25 19:56:44 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
2017-01-25 19:56:44 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 TLS go ahead
2017-01-25 19:56:44 SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
2017-01-25 19:56:44 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2017-01-25 19:56:44 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 prime.mycompany.ro closing connection
2017-01-25 19:56:44 SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

Comment: are you trying this on your localhost?

Comment: No, I am on a shared hosting. I tested the php mail function and it works.

Comment: try to change $this->isSendmail() with $this->isSMTP()

Comment: I don't want to use SMTP protocol, I want to use sendmail. If I want to use SMTP I have to configure more things.

Comment: Here can be possible solution of your answer: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4393724/phpmailer-reports-could-not-execute-usr-sbin-sendmail

Comment: The path is correct, I checked it in phpinfo. But I don't know what should I do regarding those permisions, where can I see them ?

Comment: ewan is right. Because you are having a shared hosting, you have not permission for sendmail. so, you can contact your service provider by submitting ticket on their website for permission

Comment: I have lots of shared hosting websites and and all I can use sendmail, it's this particular one. And as I said, in phpinfo I see sendmail_path /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i  ; Does this mean that I can use sendmail protocol?

Answer (score 3):

Why are you using `isSendmail()` at all? You should only need it if you have a weird, customised sendmail emulation that requires more control over it than `mail()` provides; it's mainly there for historical reasons from back when that was more common (PHPMailer has been around since 2001!).

If you simply do nothing, PHPMailer defaults to using PHP's built-in `mail()` function. However, I'd recommend you avoid that and use `isSMTP()` anyway - it's more reliable, faster, more secure, and provides better feedback on sending. If `mail()` works, all it should involve is adding:

```
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'localhost';
```

Leaving everything else with defaults should be fine. This is significantly less hassle than customising a sendmail config.

Also, you're not helping yourself by not setting `Body` - that may be the cause of your error. If you want to send a plain-text-only message, do this:

```
$mail->isHTML(false);
$mail->Body = 'Hello';
```

Comment: I avoid SMTP because it is harder to configure, or at least I don't know how. I should set a host, a port, auth, use, password, I don't know this data. I tried once and got an error also.

Comment: If you can call `mail()`, it means you have a mail sever running on localhost, and it will be listening on the default port 25. I've told you all you need - it's just those 2 lines - all you need to do is tell it to use SMTP and talk to localhost. Everything else just stays as defaults - you don't need any username, password, encryption or anything else.

Comment: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Comment: So follow the link and do what it says?

Comment: I've added debug 2, and $mail->SMTPSecure = false; but it doesn't work. I get an error: 220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited ,220 and/or bulk e-mail. SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.

Comment: That's not an error - it's just a welcome banner - add the full transcript to your question please.

Comment: OK, so your ISP intercepts SMTP traffic and directs it to their own server, which offers TLS, so PHPMailer tries to use it automatically. You can disable that with `$mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false;`. You're seeing a failure as soon as you try to start TLS, which is covered in the guide - probably a misconfigured certificate or PHP installation.

Comment: Yes, it worked with this. Thanks. I will give you a thumbs up for your answer, I think it's a good think to add this also in your answer so that anybody can see it. Meanwhile I still try to see why sendmail is not working along with the company. I am waiting for a response because I opened a tiket few minutes ago and in case I find something, I will post the answer here.

Comment: Glad that worked! You probably would have been ok simply not calling `isSendmail` as it would have fallen back to regular `mail()` sending, which should have worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve your probleme by :

- Using SMTP server ( delete isSendmail(); and replace by $mail->IsSMTP(); )
- Try to update sendmail
- Check if Web user can access to sendmail
- Use mail function to send email
- Try to restart Apache or your web server

Comment: I don't want to use SMTP server, I don't want to use the simple mail function. I want to use phpmailer with smtp. What do you mean that I should update sendmail? or user can access sendmail?

Comment: If your are on a shared hosting, it's possible your host do not allow sendmail and you need to contact them

Comment: Is there any way I can know if they alow sendmail? Because in my phpinfo I can see sendmail_path /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i